# Android - Calling System.loadLibrary() causes process to die

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I've decided to take on porting a game, that uses SDL libraries and makes heavy use of C++ and the STL, over to Android.  I've been successful in getting all the required libraries compiled as well as all the source files for the game.  My problem is that when I call System.loadLibrary() to load the .so for the game, the app immediately crashes with "Process org.libsdl.app (pid 3569) has died."

Here is the section of code where I load all the needed libraries and the game as a shared library.

```
    static {
       // Load the required libraries for the game
       System.loadLibrary("SDL");
       System.loadLibrary("SDL_image");
       System.loadLibrary("SDL_mixer");
       System.loadLibrary("SDL_net");
       // load the game as a shared library
       System.loadLibrary("smw_jni"); // << process dies when this is called
    }
```

libswm_jni.so was compiled with the Android NDK and in the Applicaion.mk file I specified

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

Since it crashes immediately after System.loadLibrary("smw_jni") with no meaningful error messages, I am at a loss as to how to go about getting to the root cause.

I've worked on porting another game which was just plain old C code, which worked out, so I am not sure if there is an issue with the fact that this particular game is heavy on the C++ side.

Thanks in advance for any help with this headache of mine!

-clark-

Comment: I just wanted to add that I also tried APP_STL := stlport_static and got the same results.  Also the device I am testing this on is an N1 with Android 2.3.5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After pulling my hair out with this one I finally figured out the problem.  It turns out one of the classes was performing some file IO on files that did not exist.  In case someone else encounters a problem with loading a shared library, here is what I did to figure this one out.

I enabled a breakpoint at the call to System.loadLibrary() and when execution halted at this breakpoint, I then used stacktrace to get some extra information which was not being provided in logcat.

Since there was quite a bit of information I had stacktrace piped out to a file so I could analyze it.  Here is the command I used

```
# adb shell strace -p pid > strace.log
```

I hope this helps anyone who comes across a similar pain in the arse problem.

-clark-

Answer (score 0):

You only need to call `loadLibaray()` on the library that actually exposes a JNI interface. They system should take care of loading any dependent libraries, so I don't think you need to to load SDL_*. What does the logcat say?

Comment: logcat says "Process org.libsdl.app (pid 3569) has died."  I was following the SDL included android example that loads the needed SDL libs and then finally calls loadLibrary() on my jni shared lib.

I tried commenting the calls to loadLibrary() for all the SDL_ libs and I then get an exception when I load my jni lib that it could not load needed library "libSDL_xxx.so."  So it looks like I do need to load those since it is dependent on them.